# Comparar os dados de um ArrayList para nao deixar cadastrar em duplicidade - Java

Tags: java, arraylist

Boa tarde a todos

Preciso comparar todos os indices desse arrayList com o indice que estiver sendo adicionado atualmente, é possivel?

```
//MENU - CADASTRAR PRODUTOS
       private void cadastrarProdutos() {
            String escolha;
            do {
                tituloPrincipal();

                System.out.println("**** INCLUSÃO DE PRODUTOS ****");
                Mercadorias mercadoria = setDadosDoProduto();
                escolha = confirmaOperacao();
                if (escolha.equalsIgnoreCase("S")) {
                    for(int i = 0; i < prodList.size(); i++) {            
                            if(prodList.get(0).getNome() == prodList.get(i).getNome()) {
                                System.out.println("Esse produto já foi cadastrado!");
                            }
                            else {
                                prodList.add(mercadoria);
                            }
                        }                         
                }
                escolha = getRepetirOperacao();

            } while (escolha.equalsIgnoreCase("S"));
            adicionarProduto();
        }
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 3):

Se você não quer que sua lista contenha elementos duplicados, a coleção correta a se usar é o `Set`. Como seu código não contempla a criação da variável `prodList`, darei a seguinte sugestão genérica para alteração do código:

```
Set<Mercadorias> prodList = new HashSet<>();
```

Para que a coleção verifique corretamente que o item já existe em seus elementos, você deve sobrescrever o método `hashCode` e `equals` da sua classe `Mercadorias`. Adicione o seguinte código a ela:

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
  return this.getNome().hashCode();
}

@Override
boolean equals(Object obj) {
  if (obj == null) {
    return false;
  }

  if (!(obj instanceof Mercadoria)) {
    return false;
  }

  if (obj == this) {
    return true;
  }

  return this.getNome().equals(((Mercadoria) obj).getNome());
}
```

Assim depois dessas alterações você pode ajustar seu código para:

```
// ...
if (escolha.equalsIgnoreCase("S")) {
  if (!prodList.add(mercadoria)) {
    System.out.println("Esse produto já foi cadastrado!");
  }
}
// ...
```

Veja funcionando no [**ideone**](https://ideone.com/9EWGLG).

---

> [**`Set`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Set.html)
>
> A collection that contains no duplicate elements.

Em tradução livre:

> Uma coleção que não contém elementos duplicados.

Comment: Se está sobrescrevendo `Object.hashCode()`, precisa sobrescrever também `Object.equals()`.

Comment: Feito, obrigado.

Answer (score -1):

No trecho

```
if(prodList.get(0).getNome() == prodList.get(i).getNome()) {
```

Você está sempre comparando o primeiro item da prodList com cada item da mesma  prodList.

Imagino que você teria que comparar com o nome da nova mercadoria, por exemplo:

```
if(mercadoria.getNome() == prodList.get(i).getNome()) {
```

Outra observação:

Quando estamos comparando objetos, precisamos usar o método equals()
no lugar de ==

```
if(mercadoria.getNome().equals(prodList.get(i).getNome()))
```

https://morettic.com.br/wp2/poo/equals-em-java/

edit:
como o @Sorack bem comentou,
a função que adiciona a mercadoria deveria ser usada de fora do loop for, da forma que colocou, a mercadoria sera adicionada diversas vezes, sempre que o nome da mercadoria avaliada for diferente.

Comment: Sua solução corrige parcialmente o código, porém não considera que ele está percorrendo a lista, portanto a porção de código que faz a inserção está no local errado.